# Change number of digits displayed

Tags: output, stata

I have some results from the `tabulate` command in Stata:

[image]

However, these appear with numbers that are too detailed such as `0.4988995`.

I want to change the number of digits in the output. For example, `0.0499` instead of `0.4988995`.

Is there any way to reduce the number of digits displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to generate new variables or use other commands such as `tabdisp`. The `tabulate` command respects a variable's `format`.

Consider the following toy example:

```
sysuse auto, clear

format mpg

  variable name  display format
  -----------------------------
  mpg            %8.0g
  -----------------------------

tabulate rep78 foreign, summarize(mpg) nofreq

              Means and Standard Deviations of Mileage (mpg)

    Repair |
    Record |      Car type
      1978 |  Domestic    Foreign |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
         1 |        21          . |        21
           | 4.2426407          . | 4.2426407
-----------+----------------------+----------
         2 |    19.125          . |    19.125
           | 3.7583241          . | 3.7583241
-----------+----------------------+----------
         3 |        19  23.333333 | 19.433333
           | 4.0856221  2.5166115 | 4.1413252
-----------+----------------------+----------
         4 | 18.444444  24.888889 | 21.666667
           | 4.5856055  2.7131368 | 4.9348699
-----------+----------------------+----------
         5 |        32  26.333333 | 27.363636
           | 2.8284271   9.367497 | 8.7323849
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total | 19.541667  25.285714 | 21.289855
           | 4.7533116  6.3098562 | 5.8664085
```

Consequently, you just need to set the desired `format` beforehand:

```
format mpg %8.3g

tabulate rep78 foreign, summarize(mpg) nofreq

             Means and Standard Deviations of Mileage (mpg)

    Repair |
    Record |      Car type
      1978 |  Domestic    Foreign |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
         1 |        21          . |        21
           |      4.24          . |      4.24
-----------+----------------------+----------
         2 |      19.1          . |      19.1
           |      3.76          . |      3.76
-----------+----------------------+----------
         3 |        19       23.3 |      19.4
           |      4.09       2.52 |      4.14
-----------+----------------------+----------
         4 |      18.4       24.9 |      21.7
           |      4.59       2.71 |      4.93
-----------+----------------------+----------
         5 |        32       26.3 |      27.4
           |      2.83       9.37 |      8.73
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |      19.5       25.3 |      21.3
           |      4.75       6.31 |      5.87
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single switch to do this, just various devices.

Here is one:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. tabulate for rep78, summarize(mpg) nost nofreq

                          Means of Mileage (mpg)

           |                Repair Record 1978
  Car type |         1          2          3          4          5 |     Total
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------
  Domestic |        21     19.125         19  18.444444         32 | 19.541667
   Foreign |         .          .  23.333333  24.888889  26.333333 | 25.285714
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------
     Total |        21     19.125  19.433333  21.666667  27.363636 | 21.289855

. egen mean = mean(mpg), by(for rep78)

. tabdisp for rep78, c(mean) format(%2.1f)

----------------------------------------------
          |         Repair Record 1978        
 Car type |    1     2     3     4     5     .
----------+-----------------------------------
 Domestic | 21.0  19.1  19.0  18.4  32.0  23.3
  Foreign |             23.3  24.9  26.3  14.0
----------------------------------------------
```

Note further that `tabstat` yields `summarize`-like results but with an option `format()`.